# Adding third party class (EmailReplyParser) to laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm struggling to add this class to laravel https://github.com/willdurand/EmailReplyParser.

I've added

```
"willdurand/email-reply-parser": "~2.2"
```

to my require in composer

and

```
 "vendor/willdurand/email-reply-parser/src/EmailReplyParser/EmailReplyParser.php"
```

to autoload>classmap

Do I need to create an alias?

When I call

```
$email = new \EmailReplyParser\Email();
```

from my controller it can't find the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create aliases for every single 3rd party package :)

This line is excessive:

```php
"vendor/willdurand/email-reply-parser/src/EmailReplyParser/EmailReplyParser.php"
```

Just follow the installation guide from package README:

```php
use EmailReplyParser\Parser\EmailParser\Email;

$email = new Email();
```

Comment: how can use this library in a yii app ?? any idea